# When can you flag again after recent flags have been declined?

Tags: support, flags, flag-ban

If one has had a recent streak of flags being declined, when does one get the permission back?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/158100) of Shog9

> ... this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week. ...

Do notice that the number of declined flags needed to be banned was reduced from 10/week to 6/week just last night as indicated again by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243601/158100). You are flag-banned when 25% of your flags have been declined in the past week.

Comment: And in this specific case, 5 days. Moderators can see the duration, but I'm not sure if that's presented in the warning or elsewhere.

Comment: @BradLarson Well that was very direct but enlightening! I don't recall seeing that information presented to the user. Thanks!

Comment: @BradLarson Its not. Perhaps the ban should link against the MSE post?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was almost going to try to get flag banned myself to see what the message says....

Comment: @rene Ironically enough, I just hit it. It look identical to the picture in the MSE post. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243600/guaranteed-flag-ban for my take on the experience.

Comment: My bad; forgot that was mod-only @BradleyDotNET